# How to count the amount of times a substring is in a csv file using python

Tags: python, file, csv, python-3.x, sum

As the title implies, I am trying to figure out how to code a program that would allow me to count how many times a substring appears in a CSV file. For example I have a csv file that states how many time a person called an unknown number and I want to write to another file the amount of times each person called a number that is unknown.

This is what my input CSV file would look like:

```
John Smith called or messaged Unknown Party(xxx-xxx-xxxx) on 11/9/2013 at 16:44 for 1 second(s).  
John Smith called or messaged Unknown Party(xxx-xxx-xxxx) on 11/12/2013 at 8:18 for 1 second(s).  
John Smith called or messaged Unknown Party(xxx-xxx-xxxx) on 11/21/2013 at 16:17 for 1 second(s).  
John Smith called or messaged Unknown Party(xxx-xxx-xxxx) on 11/21/2013 at 13:51 for 1 second(s).  
John Smith called or messaged Unknown Party(yyy-yyy-yyyy) on 11/1/2013 at 16:26 for 1 second(s).  
John Smith called or messaged Unknown Party(yyy-yyy-yyyy) on 11/1/2013 at 16:45 for 21 second(s).  
Jane Smith called or messaged Unknown Party(zzz-zzz-zzzz) on 11/21/2013 at 10:41 for 2 second(s).  
Jane Smith called or messaged Unknown Party(zzz-zzz-zzzz) on 11/21/2013 at 15:52 for 4 second(s).
```

An example of the output file I would want is as follows:

```
John Smith called or messaged Unknown Party 6 time(s).      
Jane Smith called or messaged Unknown Party 2 time(s).
```

Any and all help would be appreciated. If I have not fully explained my problem, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: This isn't a code-writing service. Where is *your* code for this, and what precisely is the problem with it?

Comment: I apologize, I thought I worded my question differently. I meant to ask for a place to begin with, because I have no idea where to even start to write the code for this. I understand this is not a place to get code written for you, however, I would hope someone might have a starting place for  me. Thanks! :)

Comment: *"Where should I start?"* isn't an on-topic question here either. You need to 1. parse the file 2. process the contents 3. write the output - pick one and start there.

Comment: study this : http://pymotw.com/2/re/ and this http://pymotw.com/2/readline/

Comment: It is not a CSV file. Just open it for reading, loop through the lines, find the `') on '`, get only the  first part, and use the `collection.Counter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the file of interest is called 'filename.txt', you can use:

```
from collections import defaultdict

counts = defaultdict(int)
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
  for line in f:
    info = line.split('(')[0]
    counts[info] += 1

for c in counts:
  print '%s %d time(s).' % (c, counts[c])
```